# Have US cable tv documentary channels always had reality tv and "controversial" topics?

Tags: documentary

When I watched cable tv in the US in 2007, and while watching cable tv in Australia in 2015 (which is mainly made up of American channels), I noticed that a lot of the documentary channels (channels about history, science, nature, and the like) had a lot of shows that either

1. Were reality tv in format, such as [Ice Road Truckers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Road_Truckers) and [Deadliest Catch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadliest_Catch).
2. Were about "controversial" topics (I'm not saying "Ancient Aliens", but "Ancient Aliens")

Have US cable tv documentary channels always been like this? If not, what caused the change?

Comment: No, documentary channels used to really show actual documentaries. I think they just realised it was cheaper to point a camera at a retard than to hire researchers and make something informative. And obviously they think we're all stupid too.

Comment: Cheaper, and sadly also more popular and lucrative.

Comment: Opiates for the masses. Cultural changes throughout the decades.

Comment: Wikipedia calls the process [Channel drift](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_drift) and TV Tropes calls it [Network decay](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NetworkDecay)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the dubious Wikipedia on the [History Channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_(TV_channel)):

> It originally broadcast documentary programs and historical fiction series. **However, since 2008, it has mostly broadcast a variety of reality television series such as Pawn Stars, Ax Men, and other non-history related content.** Additionally, the network is frequently criticized by scientists, historians, and skeptics for broadcasting pseudo-documentaries, unsubstantiated and sensational investigative programming, such as Ancient Aliens, UFO Hunters, Brad Meltzer's Decoded and the Nostradamus Effect.